# Scrolling to show div elements

Tags: javascript, scroll, hide, show

I'm wanting to show two divs when the page has been scrolled, but once they've appeared not be hidden anymore. The following code works for showing the divs but once I scroll back to the top they hide.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $("#tip-2").show();
        $("#now-available").show();
    } else {
        $("#tip-2").hide();
        $("#now-available").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
var madeVis = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $("#tip-2").show();
        $("#now-available").show();
        madeVis = true;
    } else if (!madeVis) {
        $("#tip-2").hide();
        $("#now-available").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Quick tip to a StackOverflow newcomer, up-vote or mark my answer as helpful if it did the trick.

Comment: Being a newcomer comes with all sorts of restrictions. One of them being a waiting period before I'm allowed to select a correct answer.